Any difference between dull and blunt in these contexts?
Okay, what I already know is that blunt is transitive verb (E.g. The setback blunted his desire to become an actor.) whereas dull can be both transitive and intransitive (E.g. The setback dulled his desire to become an actor. & His desire to become an actor dulled upon experiencing a setback.)
Collins says about dull (v)

If something dulls or if it is dulled, it becomes less intense, bright, or lively.
“He can dull your senses with facts and figures.”

About blunt it says,

verb If something blunts an emotion, a feeling, or a need, it weakens it.
“The constant repetition of violence has blunted the human response to it.”

Oxford Languages says:

verb make or become dull or less intense
[with obj.] time dulls the memory
[without obj.] Alberts's eyes dulled a little

Merriam-Webster defines blunt (v)

transitive verb
to make less sharp, definite, or forceful
“…blunted their criticism by praising her enthusiasm”

But are there any other subtleties I should be aware of in order to know which word is the best choice?

Many people find it disconcerting to witness how rapidly their skills can be dulled/blunted by infrequent use.
They never blunt/dull their criticism.
The negative feedback dulled/blunted her interest in continuing her university education.


"They never dull their criticism" is not really great. Though one can sharpen one's criticism. A knife becomes dull or blunt. So, in general, I'd avoid dull or blunt as a verb + criticism. It's complicated because dull also means boring.

I would offer that to my American ear, the verb blunt can convey somewhat more abruptness of the decrease, while dull can suggest a more gradual decline. Perhaps my having that feeling about the two verbs’ respective meanings is affected by the adjectival sense of blunt to describe people or statements, which does carry a sense of directness, to-the-pointness, and thus more briefly delivered than spun out over time.

They're just metaphors (same as deadened his desire and probably others). But you could just use more literal reduced, lessened, decreased,... to be a bit safer.

I can't see a use case in the example, because how can doing nothing either dull or blunt your skills? They are transitive words.

In an adjectival sense, a blunt person is very different from a dull one.

I was asking about the verbs not the adjectives but thanks. There are some skills that will be subject to deterioration if not used frequently.

You were, and I was illustrating that they are not interchangeable. "There are some skills that will deteriorate if not used frequently." Welcome to Stack Exchange! Please address users like @S635 if you want them to be pinged.

The negative feedback made her lose interest in continuing her university education.

Their criticism never stops. Their criticism is unending. Dull and blunt don't quite have it.

I have seen blunt used this way in a dictionary

I don't think we can do better than those dictionaries...One can sharpen one's skills, so I guess we can say "My skills were dulled from not using them" for example.
